# How do I hide a adjacent div when I mouseout of a menu item, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I could reverse the click triggered in this function on 'mouseout' of 'a.menu-arrow'? See code below:

```
$(".menu-arrow").hover(function() {
  $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).click();
  }, this), 500));
}, function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
});
```

What happens is after 0.5 of a second of hovering over a.menu-arrow...a click is triggered showing a adjacent div containing the submenu. This is how the HTML is structured unfortunately.

Any help would be greatly aprreciated.

Sorry I'm a novice at JavaScript & JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$(this).click()` is not useful without a event handler function, to trigger an event virtually you need to use a **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** on an element, I believe you had a corresponding  event handler function written before.

Ref : **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**, **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

Comment: Sorry I implemented `.trigger('click');` but it did hide the adjacent submenu div when I mouseout of a.menu-arrow

Comment: Sorry no ...unfortunately it the menus system of a intranet system I'm working on

Comment: @Avinash - how can I write a similar function. Lets say on mouseover a.no-submenu ...if I've been hovering over this for 1 second ...then the next adjacent DIV is set to .hide();

Comment: @nasir, In your page, firebug show  `$(".menu-arrow")`  as NULL. which means the element with class name `menu-arrow` is missing in your page. please take time to update your page & one more thing, just post required module of your Question, it's difficult to search entire page. Got my point ?